# Assigning html variables to HTML elements... not working for me

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript. There is definitely 2 input tags with the name "attachments" in my form:

```
<input name="attachments" type="hidden" value="test.doc">
<input name="attachments" type="hidden" value="test2.doc">
```

Here is my javascript. It says variable attachments is undefined in my browsers:

```
var attachments = document.getElementsByName('attachments');

var picCnt = 0;
var resumeCnt = 0;

if(document.getElementsByName('attachments').length >0){
    for(var i = 0; i <= attachments.length; i++){
        if(attachments[i].value.substring(attachments[i].value.length-4, attachments[i].value.length) == ".doc" ||
        attachments[i].value.substring(attachments[i].value.length-5, attachments[i].value.length) == ".docx" ||
        attachments[i].value.substring(attachments[i].value.length-4, attachments[i].value.length) == ".pdf" ){
            resumeCnt += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this incorrect? TIA!

Comment: This looks wrong `attachments[i].value.substring(attachments[i].value-5, attachments[i].value) == ".docx"`. Are you missing a comma? What do you expect `"some string" - 5` to do? I probably gives you `NaN` (**not a number**).

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('attachments');` looks alright btw. I think there problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you running that JS on domready or below the actual elements its trying to access? This could be your issue... If you're firing this script in the `<head/>` and not waiting for the full dom to be accessed.

Comment: Frits, you're right. It should be:     `attachments[i].value.substring(attachments[i].value.length-5, attachments[i].value.length) == ".docx"` and I made the change in my code above, but that wasn't the issue.

Comment: subhaze, this runs as a function after the page has loaded. Sorry I didn't specify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is the `undefined` issue:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= attachments.length; i++){
```

It should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++){
```

It's most likely reporting `attachments[attachments.length]` is `undefined`, because it always will be.

**just a suggestion**

I found the above rather difficult to read, it's far more optimal to use a singular variable rather than repeat the same array access each time.

```
var attachments = document.getElementsByName('attachments'),
    picCnt = 0;
    resumeCnt = 0;
    i, val
;

if(attachments.length >0){
    for(i = 0; i <= attachments.length; i++){
        val = attachments[i].value;
        if(val.substring(val.length-4, val.length) == ".doc" || 
           val.substring(val.length-5, val.length) == ".docx" ||
           val.substring(val.length-4, val.length) == ".pdf" ){
        resumeCnt += 1;
    }
}
```

}